# Where on Earth has the least changing temperature?

Tags: atmosphere, temperature, geography, mapping

Is there a map that shows places where the temperature changes the least season to season? Is there a place on Earth where the temperature is the most constant in a comfortable range?

Comment: define nice,is the temparature on a sunny beach nice or is it nice if you can work outside whitout beeing to cold or hot.or is it nice if it never gets too hot or too cold.

Comment: These are two different questions. If the temperature varies between -20° and -22° I doubt that the answer to your first question is the same as to the second ;-) Please [edit] and make it 1) and 2) or leave the second out alltogether (that will depend on *why* you are asking the question).

Comment: At the moment I'm voting to close as "unclear what you're asking", because there are two different questions here (and one is opinion-based). If it were reduced to the question in the title, with perhaps some explanation as to why it's of interest, I would gladly vote to re-open.

Comment: I answered this question on quora.com, but was banned there, so I only have the answer in "github" form: https://github.com/barrycarter/bcapps/blob/master/QUORA/bc-moderate-temperature.m and the image https://github.com/barrycarter/bcapps/blob/master/QUORA/image16.gif -- feel free to format it and post it as a self-answer, I'm too lazy to do so.

Comment: I can be reopened pretty easily :-)  I agree, I think it decent to wait a day or two in many situations.  But at least the question is reasonable enough that with those little tweaks, it can be back open quite quickly likely :)

Comment: @Muze that's how the system is meant to work. People vote to close because it's unclear. That prevents people from giving confused answers to a confused question. You clarify the question, and people will automatically be asked to vote to reopen. AFAICS you haven't actually clarified the question at all, you have only complained about it being closed?

Comment: @Geochron aswered it very well and he understood the question.

Comment: Think comfortable range might be seen as just as ambiguous/subjective as nice?

Comment: I agree with @Muze - perhaps its not scientifically correct question, but if you are going to be so an#l about everything you gonna end up with dead website as no normal people would go here.. also it has to be seen whether any of you are real scientists anyway.. there are some many fantasists on the internet.. you know ;)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To answer the first question, yes, there are maps showing the seasonal temperature variation, for example [here](http://ftp.comet.ucar.edu/ootw/tropical/textbook_2nd_edition/navmenu.php_tab_2_page_6.1.0.htm) [image]

Unsurprisingly, the equatorial areas have the least variation because the angle of the sun relatively to the earth changes the least with seasons.

Regarding nice weather- I have worked as a geologist in northern South America and the Caribbean. In the lower lying areas (e.g. Aruba) I often thought it was too hot to be pleasant to work, but beachgoers think that was perfect weather. In the mountains it was often more pleasant, subjectively.
One city I visited where the temperature is remarkably stable is Medellin in Colombia - the "city of eternal spring". Situated close to the equator, temperature is always nice there ([daily mean at 22 degrees throughout the year](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Medell%C3%ADn#Climate)), but it can have a lot of rainy days.

Comment: vote to reopen? You made perfect sense of it.